# Distinct Using Condition Linq

Tags: sql, linq

So I have been spending sometime with this linq and couldn't come up with an optimal solution. Considering the following linq

[image]

I want to be able to select the distinct entries based on the BaseItemID value, so for example whenever I have two Chicken entries, I want to select the second entry because it superseeds the first entry. Another way to phrase it is whenever an entry have a BaseItemID value, pick this entry and remove the base entry from the list, so the list would be returned with the Item 1003 removed. Yet another way to phrase the condition is to select only the items that doesnot have their ID value existing in any row in the BaseItemID field.

The problem would have been easy if I can group by the name for example, and then pick the item with the *BaseItemID != null and Count > 1*, but thats not the case and the Name field is not unique and i cant really depend on it for the grouping.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to join the table on itself:

```
from i in Items
where i.Category.ServiceProviderID == 2
&& !Items.Any(ii=>ii.BaseItemID == i.ID)
```

You should do a `join` though, that should be better performant.